# Filtering Playa entries in the drop panes loads site index template

Tags: playa

When I start typing to filter entries in the Playa drop pane my list of entries is being replaced by my homepage template. There are no javascript errors. What could cause this?

I'm using Playa 4.3.3 on EE 2.5.5.

Edit: As suggested by Jérôme below, removing this from my .htaccess fixes the issue:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can I deal with this?

Comment: If you have an .htaccess on your site, can you disable it temporarily and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme, that does fix it. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: Well, Lisa did it. I blame timezones ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the index.php shouldn't be an issue, but you can try adding to /system/expressionengine/config/config.php:

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = "/index.php";
```

It may also be worth trying:

```
$config['assets_cp_path'] = "./";
```

those should get you moving forward with your .htaccess in place.  Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Another somewhat ridiculous way to cause this problem, is to do some HTML prototyping in a file called index.html and keep that in your EE set up, therein confusing the Playa because things aren’t being properly routed through index.php

Yes, I am ashamed to admit that’s what caused this for me.